# how to grab only the lines that have Allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx in the .htaccess file

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to grab all the Allowed addresses in my .htaccess files.
currently my .htaccess file looks like this

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /admin [L]
Deny from all
Allow from 192.168.0.100
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

I have this code

```
 $myfile = fopen("../.htaccess", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
        $x =  fread($myfile,filesize("../.htaccess"));
        print_r(explode("\r\n",$x));
        fclose($myfile);
```

it reads the complete file and the output is

```
Array ( [0] => Options +FollowSymlinks RewriteEngine On RewriteRule ^$ /admin [L] Deny from all Allow from 192.168.0.100 Allow from 127.0.0.1 #RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^127.0.0.1 #RewriteRule (.*) http://google.com [R=301,L] #RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^127.0.0.1 #RewriteRule index.php$ /admin [R=301,L] )
```

All I want is the Allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx in an array. I think I would need some kind of regex but am not too sharp with regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't need a regex for this:

```
$lines = array_filter(file('../.htaccess'), function($value) {
   return (stristr($value, 'allow from') !== FALSE);
});
```

*$lines* will be:

```
Array
(
    [4] => Allow from 192.168.0.100
    [5] => Allow from 127.0.0.1
)
```

**file()** will read each line into an array, **array_filter()** with a callback using **stristr()** (insensitive string compare) will filter out the lines that don't contain 'allow from'.  If you need the array to start at offset 0, you can wrap array_filter in **array_values()** to reindex the array.

Comment: Interesting solution, although seems to pick up `Allow from all` - not sure if that matters. One question about this, any idea why when doing a `print_r` on the resulting array it's output is double-spaced?

Comment: @l'L'l, double spaced?  I'm not seeing that for mine.  About allow from all, that is true, it will match anything allow from.  The filter callback could be changed quite easily, even include regex if they wanted.

Comment: Yeah for some odd reason it's double-spaced when I print it, strange - http://pastebin.com/YHArLsXe. Regex is possible in that too? Now that is cool; I'd love to see that.

Comment: Any function is possible in the callback for array_filter.  When the callback returns false, it will remove the corresponding value.

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you're asking:

```
preg_match_all( '|(?mi-Us)Allow From \d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|', $x[0], $matches) ;

print_r($matches);
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Allow from 192.168.0.100
            [1] => Allow from 127.0.0.1
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

I vote for `file()` too. Here is less dirtier way with plain simple foreach loop.

```
$result = array();
$fileArray = file('.htaccess');

foreach($fileArray as $n => $line)
{
    if(strpos($line, 'Allow from') !== false)
    {
        if(trim($line) !== "")
        {
            $result[$n] = trim($fileArray[$n]);
        }
    }
}

$result = array_values($result);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Look to my answer for a much easier way to do this using array_filter.

Comment: Yes. I know. I actually gave You upvote before I wrote another example. Autolycus won't get headaches, because of two working solutions I suppose. :)

Comment: Yes, no harm in it.  I think using array filters, maps, walks with anonymous functions  come in real handy in programming so I try to provide a lot of answers with them to show how quickly they can manipulate arrays.

Comment: That's right. foreach can be much more intensive than 'singleliners' if someone is an expert in missusing those.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do it for you :)
Also a great tool to test quick Regex expressions - **http://www.regexr.com/**

```
$myfile = fopen("../.htaccess", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$x =  fread($myfile,filesize("../.htaccess"));
$pattern = '/(Allow .*)/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches);
fclose($myfile);
```